# Invalid product identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have tried numerous ways to fix this error, but they haven't fix my problems.

I used `NSLog` and found out that the method `productRequest:didReceiveResponse` wasn't called.

But I don't know what could cause this.

**Here are the things that I have tried:**

- Upload the binary
- Delete app from the device and reinstall it from xcode
- waited for a day after i submit the product in iTunes connect
- checked 'clear for sale'
- doubled checked that i use the full product ID when making the request

Basically i tried everything from Troy Brant's post

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

But I'm still getting this error.

Please answer if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Ensure that you have a `SKProductsRequestDelegate` and that the `SKProductsRequest` delegate object is being set.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I forgot to set the delegate. If you can, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have an `SKProductsRequestDelegate` and that the `SKProductsRequest` delegate object is being set, otherwise no messages will get passed around appropriately.